# select id that created dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, intel-xdk

I wrote the below jQuery code, in this code when I click on #addbtn 2 text-box with this code below is created

```
var i = 2;
/* button  #add_btn */
$(document).on("click", "#add_btn", function(evt) {
  $('.add_checkbox').append("<input type='checkbox' id=foodcheckbox_" + i + " style='margin-bottom:20px;'><br/>");

  $(".add_food").append("<input class='wide-control form-control default input-sm foodha' type='text' placeholder='Food' id=food_input" + i + " style='margin-bottom:5px;'>");

  $(".add_price").append("<input class='wide-control form-control default input-sm priceha' type='text' placeholder='Price' id='price_input" + i + "' style='margin-bottom:5px;'>");
  i++;
});
```

This code works fine, but when I want to select text-boxes that are added with the above code to get the content of them the selector by id isn't working, below is the code that I use to get value of these text-boxes:

```
/* button  Submit */
$(document).on("click", ".uib_w_60", function(evt) {
  var foodid = [];
  var priceid = [];
  /* your code goes here */
  /* first I get id of .foodha class */
  $(".foodha").each(function() {
    var IDss = $(this).prop("id");
    foodid.push(IDss);

  });
  /*  second I get id of .priceha class */
  $(".priceha").each(function() {
    var pID = $(this).prop("id");
    priceid.push(pID);

  });

  var newfoodpriceid = [];
  /* here I dont know why the Id that gotten save
  twice in array, for example save with this pattern 
  [food_input2, food_input3, food_input2, food_input3]
  and to prevent this I use a trick and save it in another
  array with the code below: */

  for (var c = 0; c < priceid.length / 2; c++) {
    newfoodpriceid.push({
      'foodid': foodid[c],
      'priceid': priceid[c]
    });

  }

  /* then I want to get value of text box with exact
     id that I select with jQuery selector but the
     selector isn't working and the returned value
     is nothing but I enter a value in text box that
     have below id: */
  var pr = $("#" + newfoodpriceid[0].priceid).val();
  $("p").text(pr);
});
```

I explain anything that I think you need to know about what I want to do.

HTML code  before I  click on addbtn to add text-boxes:

```
<div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_42 row-height-42" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
  <div class="col uib_col_46 col-0_1-12_1-7" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col center">
      <div class="add_checkbox" style="margin-top:5px"></div>
      <span class="uib_shim"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col uib_col_48 col-0_6-12_6-7" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
      <div class="add_food"></div>
      <span class="uib_shim"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col uib_col_47 col-0_5-12_5-5" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

      <div class="add_price"></div>
      <span class="uib_shim"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="uib_shim"></span>
</div>
```

And that HTML code after click on "add btn" twice

```
<div class="add_food">
  <input class="wide-control form-control default input-sm foodha" type="text" placeholder="Food" id="food_input2" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
  <input class="wide-control form-control default input-sm foodha" type="text" placeholder="Food" id="food_input3" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
</div>

<div class="add_price">
  <input class="wide-control form-control default input-sm priceha" type="text" placeholder="Price" id="price_input2" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
  <input class="wide-control form-control default input-sm priceha" type="text" placeholder="Price" id="price_input3" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
</div>
```

As you can see the text-box with the id that I want is generated fine, but I can't select it with using its id.

Comment: Could you please add enough of your HTML (and CSS if necessary) so that we can reproduce your problem? See the "[MCVE]" guidelines for advice on what we expect, and what would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidThomas I add html code that you need

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see in your code is that once the page has run you must re-call the "each" function from jquery. When this "loop" is performed there are no "foodha" or "priceha" class cointaining elements. You could put the

```
  $(".foodha").each(function() {
    var IDss = $(this).prop("id");
    foodid.push(IDss);

  });
```

in a sleep loop or in a js function which you would call later.Like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(".foodha").each(function() {
    var IDss = $(this).prop("id");
    foodid.push(IDss);

  });
},1000); //for a second delay
```

or

```
function call_after_creating(){
   $(".foodha").each(function() {
      var IDss = $(this).prop("id");
      foodid.push(IDss);
   });
}
```

Comment: I do it but the id i selected didn't show any result